# Ruby on Rails console with where("value" < "value1")

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails and trying to get values from the database.
How to get that value, while using the Rails Console?

```
Stat.where("user_health" < "user_max_health").pluck(:id)
```

I need a working command, this one doesn't work.

The `Stat` model has an `id`, `user_health` and `user_max_health` columns.

I'm using SQLite on development and PG on production, but I need to work on both.

Comment: what's the column name ?

Comment: `Stat.group("user_health").having("user_health < user_max_health").pluck(:id)` will work I think.

Comment: seems quite working, testing or i get the right values :)

Comment: try Stat.where('user_health < user_max_health').pluck(:id)

Comment: which is faster performed? i need to run this command every 0.5 second for my whole database

Comment: [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460127/ruby-on-rails-console-with-wherevalue-value1?noredirect=1#comment43356912_27460127) answer. This is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stat.where('user_health < user_max_health').pluck(:id)